# Collapsing columns based on differences between groups using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to collapse multiple columns across groups such that the remaining summary statistic is the difference between the column values for each group. I have two methods but I have a feeling that there is a better way I should be doing this.

Example data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test <- data.frame(year = rep(2010:2011, each = 2),
               id = c("A","B"),
               val = 1:4,
               val2 = 2:5,
               stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Using summarize_each

```
test %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarize_each(funs(.[id == "B"] - .[id == "A"]), val, val2)
```

Using tidyr

```
test %>% 
  gather(key,val,val:val2) %>% 
  spread(id,val) %>% 
  mutate(B.less.A = B - A) %>% 
  select(-c(A,B)) %>% 
  spread(key,B.less.A)
```

The summarize_each way seems relatively simple but I feel like there is a way to do this by grouping on id somehow? Is there a way that could ignore NA values in the columns?

Comment: `test %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise_at(vars(-id), diff)`? I'm not sure what you want; it's going to be hard to do in fewer than two calls.

Comment: @alistaire, you might also want to `arrange(id)` to ensure that all the groups are always ordered the same way by `id`.

Comment: True, I'm not quite sure what possible arrangements the data could take; if it's out of order or has more than one row per `year` and `id` or has other `id`s, more cleaning is in order.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, lapply(.SD, diff), by = year, .SDcols = val:val2]
#   year val val2
#1: 2010   1    1
#2: 2011   1    1
```